# git revert を実行した後にコミットを確定出来ません

Tags: git, vscode

現在以下のような履歴です。"add revert"というコミットを削除したという履歴を残しつつ削除したいと思います。
そこで**git revet**を使っていきます。

[image: git log --oneline --all --graph]

ちなみに"add revert"では以下の画面のように便宜的に"revert.txt"というファイルを作成しています。

[image: git show HEAD]

この状態でターミナルに

```
git revet HEAD
```

と打ち込むと以下のような画面になります。コミット名はデフォルトで設定されているままで構いません。
ただ、ここからどのような操作をすると確定出来ますか？
「q」,「Esc」, 「ESC」を押しながら「wq」など色々試してみたのですがこの画面から抜けられません。

[image: git revert HEAD]

仕方なく上記の画像のように「X」ボタンで閉じ git status で状態を見てみると以下のようにコミットされていません。

[image: git status]

```
git revert HEAD
```

を打った直後の画面からどのような操作をすればコミットメッセージを確定出来るのでしょうか？

端末はWindows11でエディタはVSCodeを使っています。
ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git revet HEAD` を実行した後の画面はコミットメッセージを編集するためのエディタが開いていますが、ターミナルから実行しているため (git-bash をインストールしているなら) Vim が起動している可能性があります。

この場合、表示された内容を保存する必要があるので、<kbd>ESC</kbd> を押した後 `:wq` と入力してみてください。
ターミナルの画面に戻り、処理が継続されるはずです。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。またよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

`git revert` コマンドを実行すると、エディタが起動し、エディタ終了まで実行が中断されます。

このとき利用されるエディタは、

- [WindowsにGitをインストールする手順(2022年1月更新)](https://www.curict.com/item/60/60bfe0e.html)

のインストール手順説明中にある、 "7.テキストエディターの設定" で選択したエディタです(追加の設定を特に行っていないのであれば)。

質問文中の画像を見る感じ、デフォルトの vim を選択しているようなので、([他の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/86161/2808)にあるように) vim の操作方法に従ってエディタを終了させてください。

---

vim の利用方法がわからないのであれば、([説明](https://opcdiary.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Image-20210823_1447_48_001.jpg)にある通り) GUI エディタを選択しておくのが良いかと思います([おそらく](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/0a55e27c2629d1544b6dd98a5e6c5093a6b6009f/installer/install.iss#L339-L350) VSCode も選択肢にあるのではないでしょうか)。

設定ファイルを編集することでも変更できると思いますが、再インストールで選択をやり直すのも手でしょう。

---

コミットメッセージを編集しなくてよいのであれば、 [`--no-edit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#Documentation/git-revert.txt---no-edit) オプションを付与して

```
git revert --no-edit HEAD
```

とすれば、そもそもエディタが起動しません。

Comment: よく理解できました。ご丁寧な解説ありがとうございました。